# Loading an image through a relative filepath

Tags: c#, image, filepath

So I have this filepath "/DataEntry/Image/RenderOriginalImage/3237319%40Research" that will return a jpg and I need to load it into a stream so I can convert it to a byte[] using binary reader. Any ideas how I would go about loading that filepath into a stream? Filestream doesn't work.

Comment: Are you talking about unix filepath or this is URL?

Comment: It's gotta be a URL since the same filepath is being used to set the source attributes of image tags

Comment: actually I think it's on my disk.

Answer (score 0):

There's not really enough information here to give you a proper answer. The file either might or might not be on your disk, and it either might or might not be accessible via a URL. That's a lot of ground to cover.

If the file is on your disk, you should be able to access it with Filestream. If Filestream is not working, then you should provide the error (preferably the full exception) in your question.

If the file is accessible via a URL, then you would need to access it using some other method. The System.Net.Webclient class is usually a good place to start. Note that you will need to give it a full URL, not a relative URL. So, something like "http://someserver.example.com/DataEntry/Image/RenderOriginalImage/3237319%40Research"